# Extracting data dynamically from master table to tables on dashboard

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have spent the last 3-4 days trying out all kind of tips and tricks found on YouTube and rest of the internet. But I don’t manage to create what I want. Now I have to swallow my pride and ask for help.

I have a big master table, or database, with all kind of information. I want to create a dashboard with a few smaller tables with just some of the information from the database.

I attached picture of a very simplified version of what I want to archive. Picture of simplified Daschboard/MDatabase:
[image: Picture of simplified Daschboard/MDatabase]

I want to show some of the cars in column C (in the database) in separate tables on the dashboard with just some of the columns from the master table. When a row is added, deleted or information is changed in the database I want the dashboard table to update. It would be neat if it updated automatically, but a refresh button would do.
I use Outlook 2010 but can’t use MS Query or PowerQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot Tables will do exactly what you want.

Select your data source `Sheet2!B3:F13` and click `Insert` > `Pivot Table`.  Choose the range where you want to put the picot table, and click `OK`.

The Pivot Table field list will appear - drag Owner, Colour and Condition to ROWS, drag Car to FILTERS. In the Pivot Table > Design ribbon, switch off Subtotals and Grand Totals, and change Report Layout to Tabular Form.

Select a car filter as required, and format to suit.

You can create multiple pivot tables in the same manner. When data in the source table is modified, you can simply refresh the pivot tables to update them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Olly!
I totally overlooked the possibility to use pivot tables. I was obsessed with using some clever code to solve it. But the use of pivot seems to be the most convenient solution.

By the way. Thanks all you excel gurus (nerds...) out there who share your knowledge in forums like this. Two weeks ago I had no knowledge about VBA, formulas etc.  Now I have managed to build a user friendly database with a dynamic dashboard and interactive user forms. Only by reading forums posts and watching You Tube tutorials.